# How to use HTML5 Datalist with MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, html-datalist

HTML5 introduces new tag `datalist`, which connected to `<input list="datalistID">` provides autocomplete functionality.

Question is - what is the best way to connect this datalist suggestion to MySQL table with high amount of rows (let's say 50K).

Comment: With such amount of data you better use jQuery autocomplete plugin.

Comment: @Nelson: Whatever the question is, jQuery Plugin is the answer, right? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to connect it is via the `data` attribute or the `<datalist>` tag which takes any URI or IRI to get the data as XML.

You can then change the URI/IRI based on the input value. And also you should limit your resultset to a useful maximum number of lines, you don't want to transfer megabytes just for auto-complete.